# Increment int value in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a value of an int from a field in a MySql database and increment it by 1 when a new record is added. What is happening, is that when the record is inserted it is placing a 1 and not adding one to the value of the field. For example, in the last record, the value is 10 so after running the query the value should be 11.

I am struggling to see why this is not working and would be grateful if someone could offer any advice as to how to amend my code to a working solution. Many thanks

php code

```
function get_ref(){
     $query = "SELECT MAX(`id_usr`) AS `max` FROM `user_usr`";
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
     $max = $row['max'];    

    $sql = 'select idcom_usr'           
    . ' from user_usr'
    . " where id_usr = '$max'"
    . ' order '
    . ' by id desc'
    . " limit 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $ref = mysql_result($result,0,"idcom_usr");
    return $ref + 1;

    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using an auto increment field in the database instead of solving your problem in code?

Comment: I assume you've considered making the column auto-increment, and have decided against that for some reason?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: the id_usr is an auto-inc and primary key. I was under the impression that there can only be 1 auto-inc in a table. Thanks

Comment: N.B The answer is in the question. Thanks

Comment: If you post some sample data and explain on it what you're trying to achieve that might help you to get your answer faster

Comment: peterm I thought that the question was explained correctly. But here goes. Very simply, there are 2 fields. First field is id and is auto-inc. The second field is an INT and contains just a number. Lets say 10. When I add a new record, I need to increment the value of the second field so 10 becomes 11. So I thought thast by getting the value of the ID I could then get this second value and just increment it by +1 as in my code. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 - I realize you want to increment a number. However, what is the *end* goal of your feature. If you increment this number via php then you will create such a hole in the feature you're coding because you have to take concurrency into account - what happens if 2 people obtain the same result for MAX(usr_id)? Both increment the number and both send the same number to the MySQL. Also, you can have only one auto_increment.

Comment: N.B Thanks. What would be the correct way to go. Please see my comment to peterm

Comment: After reading the last comment you made, this looks like a job for an after insert trigger. You should implement it as a pure MySQL solution without having any php in it.

Comment: N.B How would I implement a trigger. That is not something I am familiar with. Thanks

Comment: Agreed with @N.B. that work should be done on db side.

Comment: @user1532468 - google is your friend in this case, there are many tutorials and examples on that topic

Comment: @user1532468 Post your table structure and sample data (a few rows) and we can help

Comment: @peterm I cannot post any client data. How is the best way to post structure.

Comment: @user1532468 Then make fake data. The best way is to create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com). Otherwise post `CREATE TABLE` statement and comma delimited data in your original question.

Comment: @peterm ok. Give me some time and I will do that. Thanks

Comment: @peterm I have created sample at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e3e8/6 but I have never used before and get error. anyway, data is there. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to achieve your goal using a trigger

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_user_usr_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON user_usr
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.idcom_usr = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(idcom_usr), 0) + 1 FROM user_usr);
```

Then when you insert new rows

```sql
INSERT INTO user_usr (idcom_usr) VALUES (0),(0);
```

Values for `idcom_usr` will be assigned by the trigger.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5989c/2)** demo.

Even if for some reason you do it in php instead of two queries you need only one

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(idcom_usr), 0) + 1 next_value 
  FROM user_usr
```

*Note: this approach is prone to errors under heavy load due to concurrency.*

Answer (score 3):

You can have the column **[auto incrementing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)**. This way you offload the work from PHP to MySQL, which is always a good thing.

Oh yeah, and [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).